# Windev Software on saas

Tags: saas, windev

Hello I don't know very much about the saas system, could you please tell me if a HR software made in windev could easily be deployed as a saas ? The problem is that it would cost a lot to deploy it, because each time a client is connected at the same time, it costs 150 euros (under windows licence). Could you please tell me more about the remote app ? And another problem is that when a client would like to print something, it opens a widows window which permits access to the network, and it is not secured. Is the only possibility to make all the windev software as a web software ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to buy Windows licences for each computer, you can :

- Generate a java application and run it on Linux, with some limitations
- Transform you application in a web app and run it on a web server, with some limitation and some more code
- Install your application on a Windows remote server and connect to it with Remote Desktop (a Windows application), but you need licences for connecting you to the server

For me, the printing problem is not a security breach.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, do I have to transform the software into java ? What are the limitations ? Thanks !

Comment: You can add a Configuration and choose Java Archive. The limitations are available here http://doc.windev.com/en-US/?9000056&name=available_features_and_limitations_java